# Looking for correct recursive algorithm for Leetcode 112

Tags: binary-tree, depth-first-search

I am working on Leet Code problem [112. Path Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum/):

> Given the `root` of a binary tree and an integer `targetSum`, return `true` if the tree has a **root-to-leaf** path such that adding up all the values along the path equals `targetSum`.
>
> A **leaf** is a node with no children.

I the code below trying to solve it, but apparently it isn't correct as I keep running into failed test cases.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {

    public boolean hasPathSum(TreeNode root, int targetSum) {

        if(root.left==null&&root.right==null&&targetSum-root.val ==0)
            return true;
        else{

            if(root.right!= null){
                hasPathSum(root.right, targetSum-root.val);
            }
            if(root.left!=null) {
                hasPathSum(root.left, targetSum-root.val);
            }

        } return false;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: if `hasPathSum(root.left, targetSum-root.val);`  or `hasPathSum(root.right, targetSum-root.val);`  is true you are still returning false.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the values returned by the recursive calls you make. In a verbose way, you could fix that part of your code as follows:

```
    boolean result = false;
    if (root.right != null) {
        result = hasPathSum(root.right, targetSum - root.val);
    }
    if (!result && root.left != null) {
        result = hasPathSum(root.left, targetSum - root.val);
    }
    return result;
```

It is more compact when you use more logical operators for that:

```
    return root.right != null && hasPathSum(root.right, targetSum - root.val)
        || root.left  != null && hasPathSum(root.left,  targetSum - root.val);
```

It is not stated explicitly in the Leet Code challenge, but when calling this function on an empty tree, it should return `false`. So you should foresee the case where `root` is `null`.

The complete solution could look like this:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean hasPathSum(TreeNode root, int targetSum) {
        return root != null && 
            (  root.left  == null && root.right == null && targetSum == root.val
            || root.right != null && hasPathSum(root.right, targetSum - root.val)
            || root.left  != null && hasPathSum(root.left,  targetSum - root.val)
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recursive solution in javascript:

```
var hasPathSum = function(root, targetSum) {

    if (root) {
        if (!root.left && !root.right) {
           return root.val === targetSum;
        }

        if (root.left) {
            const isTherePath = hasPathSum(root.left, targetSum - root.val);
    
            if (isTherePath) return true;
        }

        if (root.right) {
            const isTherePath = hasPathSum(root.right, targetSum - root.val);
    
            if (isTherePath) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```